# HMTL5 section element

Tags: html, element, variable-assignment, program-entry-point

I have an assignment due in on the 18th of August 2014, and have now been told that I need to add certain section elements to my website. However, I do not know how to use them.  what are the header, nav, main, article, aside, and footer elements use for and how do I use them in my website?

Comment: Learn HTML5 from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp) and see [How to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since HTML is a Markup Language, there are specific tags that it outlines which are essentially considered "the right ones to use" in different places of your code. For example, if you were to put a navigation bar in your site, you would use the "nav" tag to outline the section in your code that contains the navigation bar code, but you could just as easily use a "div" without causing any different behavior. Now with that said,

- Nav: The section that is usually just the top section of your page that holds links to different parts of your site (see the top of this page, however if you look at this page's source code you will notice they do not even use nav tags as specifically named tags such as these are not mandatory, you can simply use divs all over the place but that is not a good practice)
- Header: The banner section if you will where the title of the page and other global information pertaining to the page exists (ie the a large representation of your site's logo or number of visitors for your site)
- Main: The actual content of your site (the **main** content)
- Article: Think of this as a blog post which typically consists of text and maybe an image
- Aside: Usually inline with an article or some other block of text used to insert additional information (ie fun facts)
- Footer: The bottom of your page which also contains links like the header, but usually are more verbose as well as copyright information (Stack overflow has a rather large one if you scroll to the bottom of this page)

You can read more about these specific tags here: [Quackit - HTML 5 Tags](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/) and good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, if i was i was to copy and paste some of my code on here when i have finished would you be able to tell me if it is ok or not?

Comment: Yeah definitely! I would be more than happy to help.